# How to create a swift WeatherKit UVIndex for testing?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, weatherkit

I want to create an instance of a WeatherKit UVIndex struct.

This is how it is defined in the Apple source code (excerpt):

```
public struct UVIndex {
    public var value: Int
    public var category: UVIndex.ExposureCategory

    // ...
}
extension UVIndex : Codable {
    // ...

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
}
```

Now, for my SwiftUI preview I want to create a dummy instance of a UVIndex.
I tried:

```
let uvIndex = UVIndex(value: 2, category: UVIndex.ExposureCategory(rawValue: "low"))
```

However it refuses to be initialised in that way, the error message says:

> Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call

Main question:
**How can I get a UVIndex instance for testing?**

Secondary question:
**How did Apple manage to hide away the default struct initialiser?**

Comment: Get a real instance of a `UVIndex` value. Then encode it using JSONEncoder. Look at the resulting JSON. Using that as a model you can create your own JSON with the values you need and create a `UVIndex` instance using `init(from:)` and a JSONDecoder.

Comment: Awesome, it works. If you make this an answer I'll gladly accept. FWIW this is the json: {"category" : "low","value" : 0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public initializer for `UVIndex` with parameters for the properties. Most likely there is a private initializer used within WeatherKit. Apple didn't intend for anyone to create instances of `UVIndex` by passing in values for the properties.

Since `UVIndex` supports `Codable`, you can obtain an instance of `UVIndex` through WeatherKit and use a `JSONEncoder` to encode the instance and then look at the resulting JSON.

Using that JSON as a reference, you can create your own JSON string with the values you need. Then create a `JSONDecoder` with your JSON and use the `init(from:)` of `UVIndex` to create your own instance.

Currently the JSON for an encoded `UVIndex` is of the form:

```json
{
    "category": "low",
    "value": 0
}
```

Of course the "category" value can be one of the [`UVIndex.ExposureCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/weatherkit/uvindex/exposurecategory) values.

The "value" property is likely an integer in the range 0...11.